# I am getting only last id from mysql database in android json

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i am making an Online App with Android Php Mysql.I have populated listview with products with products name. But i want to get id of those items when clicking on it. But when i parse "products_id" in android. i am getting Only last Product_ID.
Here is my code:

```
   try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(aVoid);
                JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("server_response");

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {


                    JSONObject obj2 = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    final int product_id = obj2.getInt("product_id");
                    String product_name = obj2.getString("product_name");
                    arr.add(product_name);
                    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ViewProduct.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
                    li_pro.setAdapter(adapter);

                   li_pro.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                       position = product_id;
                          // i = product_id;
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                   });
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(ViewProduct.this, "" + ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: because you are not adding your product_id to any list and you are reassigning the value of product_id inside loop,hence, at last, you get the last value you provided thought loop.

Comment: Nothing Happened. and i populated the items in listview and retrieving it successfully. But when i click on any item i am getting the last item id.
and i dont want to show user a "PRODUCT_ID".

Answer (score 0):

You are adding adapter in for loop so for  every item in loop is setting 
        adapter that's why you are getting only item.
        Set Adpater after for loop will solved problem like below.

```
try {
       JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(aVoid);
       JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("server_response");

       for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject obj2 = array.getJSONObject(i);
           final int product_id = obj2.getInt("product_id");
           String product_name = obj2.getString("product_name");
           arr.add(product_name);
       }
       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ViewProduct.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
       li_pro.setAdapter(adapter);

       li_pro.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                   position = product_id;
                   // i = product_id;
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
       });

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Toast.makeText(ViewProduct.this, "" + ex, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: atlast i got the solution. :)